# Resizing an ImageView within a TableLayout programmatically

Tags: android

If I have a TableLayout structure (below) which defines 2 ImageViews. One which also specifies pixel values for width/height. This works as I would expect - Pic one is resized to 50px and pic2 is kept at its original size:

```
<TableLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TableRow>
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/pic1" android:layout_width="50px" android:layout_height="50px" />
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/pic2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

**But I really need to do the above programmatically so I do it like this...**

```
TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(ctx);
TableRow tableRow = new TaleRow(ctx);

ImageView imageViewOne = new ImageView(ctx);
ImageView imageViewTwo = new ImageView(ctx);
imageViewOne.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic1);
imageViewTwo.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic2);

imageViewOne.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(50, 50));

rootView.addView(tableLayout);
tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
tableRow.addView(imageViewOne);
tableRow.addView(imageViewTwo);
```

The above doesn't do the same as the XML - The first ImageView does not show at all using the programmatic way after adding the setLayoutParams() method to it.

**I mist be missing something here, what is it that is different?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok I've managed to solve this. Instead of using:

```
imageViewOne.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(50, 50));
```

I used this instead:

```
imageViewOne.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(50, 50));
```

Comment: thank you for posting your solution.  this helped me immensely!