# How to Change size of ImageView Dynamically?

Tags: android, dynamic, tablelayout

I am creating a dynamic table whose rows contains a imageview and a textview. My problem is this imageview is taking full size of original image but I want to change the size of imageview.I have used setLayoutParams which has no effect.
As an alternative I also used textview instead of imageview and set image as textview's background and used setWidth and setHeight but it has the same problem.
Plz Help Me.

Comment: @Sujit I will accept answer only when I get the solution.So far not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found the Solution

[Resizing an ImageView within a TableLayout programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188763/resizing-an-imageview-within-a-tablelayout-programmatically)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the [scaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android%3ascaleType)-Attribute?

---

Check out the `setMaxWidth` and `setMaxHeight`-methods of the ImageView-class:

> To set an image to be a maximum of 100
>   x 100 while preserving the original
>   aspect ratio, do the following: 1) set
>   adjustViewBounds to true 2) set
>   maxWidth and maxHeight to 100 3) set
>   the height and width layout params to
>   WRAP_CONTENT.

[Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setMaxWidth%28int%29)

Comment: Try cleaning off everything you tested and then use the Tip provided by the Android Docs (my quote). If it's still not working, you might want to have a look in the standard [Android Contact Book](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts) and see how they do it.

Comment: Did you look into the Contact Books Source Code? What version are you targeting?

Comment: This worked for me, I was missing that I had to set the adjustViewBounds attribute. Once I set that, MaxHeight and MaxWidth worked.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your image is a drawable resource, you can use ScaleDrawable instead, and use the xml attributes `android:scaleHeight` and `android:scaleWidth` to shrink your image.

Comment: Thanks for replying.I am dynamically creating imageview and I didn't find the equivalent methods for scaleHeight and scaleWidth.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your ImageView's layout_width and layout_height inside the layout file to some constant values measured in sp, for example `100sp`. This will make all ImageViews look the same.

Comment: Thanks for replying.I am dynamically creating imageview and I have not used any layout file I am creating ImageView object and using it.